# Polymorphic Associations Status in concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created concern in which placed association.

I need to make polymorphic association status.

```
has_one :status, class_name: 'VideoStatus', inverse_of: :video, dependent: :destroy

belongs_to :video, inverse_of: :status
```

I can't make that Association.How to make it?

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module EncodeStatuses
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  FORMATS  = %w[mp4]

  HIGH_VERSION   = 'high'
  MEDIUM_VERSION = 'medium'
  LOW_VERSION    = 'low'

  VERSIONS = [HIGH_VERSION, MEDIUM_VERSION, LOW_VERSION]

  included do
    has_one :status, class_name: 'VideoStatus', inverse_of: :video, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :status, update_only: true
    delegate :success?, :failure?, :waiting?, :encoding?, to: :status
  end
end
```

models/video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EncodeStatuses
  ...
end
```

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include EncodeStatuses
  ...
end
```

models/video_status.rb

```
class VideoStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_WAITING  = 'waiting'
  STATUS_ENCODING = 'encoding'
  STATUS_SUCCESS  = 'success'
  STATUS_FAILURE  = 'failure'

  STATUSES = [STATUS_WAITING, STATUS_ENCODING, STATUS_SUCCESS, STATUS_FAILURE]

  belongs_to :video, inverse_of: :status
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :status
  ...
end
```

Comment: did you placed association inside "included" block?

Comment: @AnilMaurya yeah, I need to make only polymorphic association the "status".

Comment: can you show your concern, so that we can debug.

Comment: @AnilMaurya I edited a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
has_one :status, as: :video_status, dependent: :destroy

class VideoStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video_status, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: and don't forgot to add video_status_id, video_status_type to video_status table